# Why the servlet doesn't work?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets

All, I am the newbie into the Java web development, I am trying to implement a Servlet in my test. But I found the Servlet I created doesn't work . I didn't know whether I had missed anything. Please help me to review it .thanks.

What I had done so far is:

1. Created a `Dynamic Web Project` named `SecondWeb` with the option
   `Generate web.xml DD`.
2. Added a `Servlet` named `HelloServlet` under the package
   `com.example.servlets`. I config the `URL Mapping` with the values
   `/HelloServlet` and `/*`. Hope it will work for all the url pattern 
   under the root.

Here is the code for it .

```
package com.example.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class for Servlet: HelloServlet
 *
 */
 public class HelloServlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet 
     implements javax.servlet.Servlet {

    /* (non-Java-doc)
     * @see javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public HelloServlet() {
        super();
    }       

    /* (non-Java-doc)
     * @see javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
         HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.getWriter().write("Hello, world!");
    }   

    /* (non-Java-doc)
     * @see javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
         HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }               
}
```

And the I also added a `index.jsp` joined the test.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>My Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<% java.util.Date d = new java.util.Date(); %>
<h1>
Today's date is <%= d.toString() %> and this jsp page worked!
</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

What I expected is I hope the `Hello world` string can be added into the `index.jsp` response `HTML` when access the URL `http://localhost:8080/SecondWeb` or `http://localhost:8080/SecondWeb/index.jsp`. But seems the `HelloServlet` doesn't work. Why? Thanks.

Comment: _`HelloServlet` doesn't work_ means its not getting called? What are you getting when you hit `http://localhost:8080/SecondWeb/index.jsp` ?

Comment: I did n't see any code to call or include the helloworld servlet in your jsp page.

Comment: @VikasV Yes . I set a breakpoint in the `doGet`, but it was not triggered. thanks.

Comment: [Reference](http://www.technicalkeeda.com/details/servlet-jsp-hello-world-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue, I have to add the `Servlet` configuration in `Web.xml`. Like below under the root element:

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.example.servlets.HelloServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```